# Where to look for qtconsole.manager documentation?

Tags: python, ipython, qtpy

I'm new to Qt5 and I'm trying to develop something that's based on a working code.
This is the following "code":

```
from qtconsole.manager import QtKernelManager

class whatever
    def __init__(self):
        super(whatever, self).__init__()
        kernel_manager = QtKernelManager(kernel_name=USE_KERNEL)
        ...

    def whatever2:
       ...
       self.kernel_manager.kernel.execution_count = 1
```

and I get an error:

AttributeError: 'QtKernelManager' object has no attribute 'kernel'

The thing is that I tried looking EVERYWHERE for this class and looked for attributes, but nothing comes up.
Does anyone have a clue how to solve this and those kinds of problems in general?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be part of the iPython project: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.qt.manager.html maybe you should look into the sources

Comment: [qtconsole](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole) / [jupyter_client](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client). There's no obvious evidence that either `kernel` or `execution_count` is a valid attribute. What happens if you comment that line out? And what is this "working code" you refer to?

Comment: It turns out that my teammates downloaded the packages and changed it in our work, so I needed to go through their code. Thanks anyway!